# Office-UI-Fabric Pivot with React Router? Possible or not?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I face real challenge (at least for me) so I decide to ask for some help here. I'm building SPFx app where I'm using Pivot from UI-Fabric and I would like  the current user to be able to navigate back and forward with browsers buttons and even be able to send url and then to navigate see specific item **within the app** (if is possible) via url for ex. (App Location: http://sharepoint/mySite/, url: http://sharepoint/mySite/DisplayItem/Item22 or http://sharepoint/mySite/Upload/Item22 or
http://sharepoint/mySite/SharedWith/Item22)

My code look like this:

```
   <Pivot>
      <PivotItem headerText="Display Item">
        <DisplayItem props={...} />
      </PivotItem>
      <PivotItem headerText="Upload">
        <Upload props={...} />
      </PivotItem>
      <PivotItem headerText="Shared with">
        <SharedWith  props={...} />
      </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
```

Obviously it doesn't work if I wrap `<PivotItem/>` or `<DisplayItem/>` as well `<Upload>` and `<SharedWith/>` with `<Link to={...}>`. Any ideas?